# Scala increment multiple variable in for loop

Tags: scala

I'm looking for a way to increment two variables in for loop like it can be done in Java:

```
for (int j = column + 1, i = row + 1; j < size && i < size; j++, i++)
```

In Scala if I write

```
for(j <- start to end; i <- start2 to end2)
```

this converts to nested loop but I need it to run in a raw and stop when first increment go to end.

Comment: What is the purpose? I am pretty sure that it could be done more idiomatically.

Comment: @sebszyller I need to increment 2 variables and combine them. It's for generating movements of bishop on chessboard. So to generate it need to increment / decrement x and y at the same time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
val column = 5; val row = 3; val size = 10; // some input..

for {
  (i, j) <- (row + 1 to size - 1) zip (column + 1 to size - 1)
} {
  println(s"i=$i j=$j")
}

/* prints:
i=4 j=6
i=5 j=7
i=6 j=8
i=7 j=9
*/
```

The trick is, you do not want to have all combinations (`for { i <- ... ; j <- ... }`) of `i`'s and `j`'s. Rather you want them to increment together.

So you can create one range `(start to end)` and `zip` it with the other one. (The operation will drop the tail of longer sequence -- that basically ensures the `j < size && i < size` condition.)

And the rest is just a syntax sugar for matching the zipped tuples as `i` and `j` variables.

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

*This is not possible using `for comprehension` because `for comprehension` gets converted into `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` calls. The expressions inside the `for comprehension` gets wrapped/nested inside `map`, `flatMap` and so nesting is unavoidable.*

```
for {
 i <- 1 to 10
 j <- 20 to 30
} yield (i -> j)
```

becomes

```
(1 to 10).flatMap { i =>
  (20 to 30).map { j =>
     (i -> j)
  }
}
```

So nesting is unavoidable.

*But if i and j start and end at same point we can do something like below*

As `i` is increasing just assign `j = i`. Note that `j` does not increase independently of `i` but atleast you will not have nesting.

```
for {
  i <- 1 to 10
  j = i if j < 5
} yield i -> j
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> for {
        i <- 1 to 10
        j = i if j < 5
       } yield i -> j
res3: collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4))
```

Comment: Sorry, I incorrectly wrote example. Start value for i and j is different so I can't assign j = i